# Borrow a vector inside a loop

Tags: vector, rust, iterator, borrow-checker

I'm trying to update each element of a vector and then borrow the entire vector during each iteration, ex:

```rust
#![allow(unused)]

#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Foo {
    value: i32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut foos: Vec<Foo> = vec![Foo { value: 1 }, Foo { value: 2 }, Foo { value: 3 }];

    for foo in &mut foos {
        update_single(foo);

        //save_all(&foos); <-- this doesn't compile - there's already a mutable borrow
    }
}

fn update_single(foo: &mut Foo) {
    println!("update_single");
    foo.value *= foo.value;
}

fn save_all(foos: &Vec<Foo>) {
    println!("save_all:");
    for foo in foos {
        println!("\t{:?}", foo);
    }
}
```

Note: I'm saving the updated vector as a blob e.g. via `serde_json`.

Comment: This is simply not allowed in Rust. But you can iterate and access by index. `for i in 0..foos.len() { … }`

Comment: Thanks Caesar. As you say, that works just fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for foo in &mut foos` will borrow the entirety of `foos` mutably throughout the entire `for` loop.

You can either borrow something mutably once or immutably any number of times, but not both. So, when you borrow the entire vector mutably for the duration of the loop, it can't be immutably borrowed again until you let go of that mutable borrow when the loop finishes.

You can get around this by borrowing each element mutably only on one line of the loop, rather than borrowing the entire vector for the entire loop.

```rust
    for i in 0..foos.len() {
        update_single(&mut foos[i]);
        save_all(&foos);
    }
```

Now we mutably get each item in the array, and it only mutably borrows each time on that one line.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I'm marking this as the correct answer. Just to clarify - it's just not possible to use an iterator here due to the need for both a mutable & an immutable borrow!?